# Internal error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'psa.domainaliases' doesn't exist

Tags: plesk

How do I resolve this error-

```
Internal error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'psa.domainaliases' doesn't exist
```

I tried upgrading from Plesk 9 to 11.0.9 and when I click on Domains, I get this error.

Please let me know.
TIA

NOTE- I moved the question to Superuser - https://superuser.com/questions/872774/internal-error-sqlstate42s02-base-table-or-view-not-found-1146-table-psa-d

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general server tech support.

Comment: Try /usr/local/psa/bootstrapper/pp11.0.9-bootstrapper/bootstrapper.sh repair